# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: dag when running in tox environment

Tags: airflow, github-actions, tox

I have a github action which is running a tox file. The tox file is running some very basic tests on apache airflow. For example:
workflow.yml

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- some more steps
- name: Run tox
      run: tox
```

tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py36
[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
commands =
    pytest
```

test_file.py

```
def test_dags():
    dagbag = DagBag(dag_folder=str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('task_manager_airflow'))) / 'dags', include_examples=False)
    dag = dagbag.get_dag(dag_id='some_dag')
```

How come I get a `no such table: dag` error when the github action runs? When I run it locally on my machine it works perfectly.

Comment: The `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: dag` error is because the test instance doesn't have access to a database. How to provide the test instance with a database is a different question ....